# How do I create typescript components in a javascript project using bit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, components, bit.dev

I want to create a few typescript components in an existing javascript project. My new components will all be placed in a single folder and will use the `react-typescript` compiler as opposed to the `react` compiler that the rest of the components use.
How can I define this complier to the entire folder (and all the components in it) but keep the existing compiler on all the existing bit components in the project?

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [override feature](https://docs.bit.dev/docs/overrides#__docusaurus) in [bit](https://github.com/teambit/bit).
Add all your new TypeScript components with a special flag(`typescript-components` in my example), so it will be easier to override the compiler for these components.
Here is an example of how the bit object in your `package.json` or `bit.json` file should look:

```
{
    "env": {
        "compiler": "bit.envs/compilers/react@1.0.6"
    },
    "componentsDefaultDirectory": "components/{name}",
    "packageManager": "npm",
    "overrides": {
        "typescript-components/*": {
            "env": {
                "compiler": "bit.envs/compilers/react-typescript@3.1.23"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, all the components in the project will use the `react` compiler, and all components with `typescript-components` [namespace](https://docs.bit.dev/docs/best-practices.html#use-namespaces) will use the `react-typescript` compiler.